# Use skip_reason as a condition in a task

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to use the `skip_reason` as condition to another task?

Here is the task:

```yaml
- name: PSP Validation
  script: roles/OS_minor_upgrade/files/PSP_validation.sh
  ignore_errors: true.
  register: PSP_VAL
  when: >
      not 'VMware' in HWMODEL.stdout
```

Which output:

```
TASK [OS_minor_upgrade : PSP Postwork] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ansible/linuxpatching_OS_Upgrade/roles/OS_minor_upgrade/tasks/upgrade.yml:264
skipping: [server123] => {
    "changed": false,
    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"
}
```

Now I want to use the above as condition to execute another task, I tried with the task below but it seem like it is not working.

```yaml
- name: OSupgrade done
 shell: echo {{ inventory_hostname }} "OS Upgrade Done" >  OUTGOING-OSUPGRADE-PATCHCOMPLETION/inventory_{{ inventory_hostname }}_{{ '%y%m%d%H%M%S' | strftime }}_Offlineoutput
 delegate_to: localhost
 when: >
    fs_check.rc == 0 and val_etrust.rc == 0 and 'PSP Installation is successfully completed' in PSP_VAL.stdout or 'Conditional result was False' in PSP_VAL.skip_reason
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can use 'skip_reason' as any other variable, but I STRONGLY suggest you not to.

The reason is that person, reading your code (you, 1 week later) would be in a total loss over such decision.

If you have important information about your host, you can use `set_fact` module to update your host information. Further tasks can use this to make decisions.

```
- name: Update vmware info
  set_fact:
      vmware_flag: ('VMware' in HWMODEL.stdout)

- name: PSP Validation
  script: roles/OS_minor_upgrade/files/PSP_validation.sh
  failed_when: false
  register: PSP_VAL
  when: not vmware_flag

- name: OSupgrade done
  delegate_to: localhost
  copy:
    dest: OUTGOING-OSUPGRADE-PATCHCOMPLETION/inventory_{{ inventory_hostname }}_{{ '%y%m%d%H%M%S' | strftime }}_Offlineoutput
    content: '{{ inventory_hostname }} "OS Upgrade Done"'
  when: (some other conditions) or vmware_flag
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [specific ansible tests to verify the registered result of a task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-task-results)

In your specific case:

```yaml
when: <...all other conditions...> or PSP_VAL is skipped
```